# multi threading Access in vba error 3260

Tags: multithreading, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to set up multithreading in Access VBA by using VB scripts. The routines are based on Tomasz Kacprowicz routines for Excel.

The methods create separate copies of the main database file which also contain the VBA functions. A script file then opens each Copy them and runs the same function in each copy. All copies of the Access Database run copies of the same function. This works fine until the function tries to open a common database.

The first copy opens the standard database, but the common database is then unintentionally locked from being opened by the other Access copies. It throws error 3260.

the VB Script is:
    {
    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

```
With objAccess
.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\Personnal\investment\7055_1.accdb")
.Run "RunForVBA", 1, 501
End With
Set objAccess = Nothing
Set objAccess = GetObject(, "Access.Application")

objAccess.TempVars.Item ("S7055_1") = 1
Do Until objAccess.TempVars.Item ("S7055_1")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Do
WScript.Shell.Sleep(100)
objAccess.TempVars.Item ("S7055_1") = 1
Loop
Set objAccess = Nothing
```

"RunForVBA" is the VBA function, and is the same in each access copy. "7055_1.accdb" is one of the copied databases.

I've checked the Default open and default locking modes. I've also tried forcing the open mode to shared in the Opendatabase and OpenCurrentDatabase Methods. It does not seem to make any difference.

the following code is in the function "RunForVBA":

```
Set DBFunc = New clsDBFunctions
Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

With DBFunc
.TableName = "TestTable"
    .DataBaseName = .GetLinkedDBName(.TableName)       'full DB path
    If .DataBaseName <> vbNullString Then    'will return 0 if no table
        Set .db = Nothing   'clear preset DB in clsDBFunctions
        Set .db = OpenDatabase(.DataBaseName, False, False) 
    End If
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe the database is being opened in "exclusive" mode , instead of "shared" mode

Comment: Ive checked the settings of the file which look ok,  the openDatabase statement defaults in shared mode, in addittion Ive set the modes to shared in the code OpenDatabase(.DataBaseName, False, False). the next couple of statements open a recordset to a table in the DB. Alternatively, if I can set this up without opening the DB?

Comment: The code you shared is apparently not sufficient to really indicate necessary details about how and when the database is being opened.  For instance, you create a new Access.Application object but then don't use it anywhere in the code you shared.  You don't reveal anything about the clsDBFunctions, but the comment about "preset DB" implies the database is being opened inside the class.

Comment: maybe it has to do with record locking  .... there are various levels .... record level, table level ..... there may also be block of records locking

Comment: You mention a "first copy" opening a "standard database", but then say that "other Access copies" are locking the "common database".  All of these terms are not fully defined.  Is there any way to describe a limited scenario of only 2 or 3 database copies and/or Access instances?  Which Access instances are opening which databases?

Comment: The sub has undergone many changes to try to get it to work. The new Access.Application object is  a hang over from a previous attempt to use the openCurrentDatabase method. I should have removed it.               "db" is being opened in the clsDBFunc, and references currentdb which is the wrong database so I set it to nothing before trying to set up the new database.

Comment: Ive just edited my original question, hopefully its a bit clearer

Comment: Im putting a hold on this, I may have solved it but needs more testing. I will update later.

Comment: Note that I have a more user-friendly way of multithreading in Access under development (can use `runAsync` which behaves like `Application.Run` only runs it in a separate thread on the same database). If you're interested I can share my current work, still working on implementing callbacks when the function is done running.

Comment: Im always interested in seeing alternate solutions.

Comment: I found the problem, it was the way that I was using the .db variable. It wouldn't quite let go of the original database instance (for some reason). I ended up creating a second database object and used that   {Dim dBase As Database:    Set dBase = OpenDatabase(.DataBaseName, False, False)}. That seemed to resolve the issue

Comment: Ive tested the code and it works well. it reduces the run time by approximately the number of cores in your CPU. let me know if anyone wants the code and ill post it.